# Attack of the mutant singular tags part XIV

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging

This time I see a new tag [weekend](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend) which should be [weekends](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekends) if it wishes to fit in with our current friendly bunch of tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done as suggested. A synonym [weekend](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend) -> [weekends](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekends) was also created.